# How do I resize tables in Visio 2010?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2010

1. Create a Database Model Diagram
2. Reverse Engineer a database (Database Tab, Reverse Engineer).

Once the diagram is created, how do you resize the tables?

I've tried:

1. Enable Developer mode, Choose `Protection`, Choose `None`. When I do that, I'm given the impression that I should be able to resize a given table but I cannot actually do it.
2. Enable Developer mode, right-click on a table, Choose `Show ShapeSheet`, Set all Lock values in the `Protection` section to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

One hack solution appears to be to replace the formulas that are baked into a table shape's height and width by default:

1. Enable Developer mode (File menu, Options, Advanced, "Run in developer mode")
2. Right-click on a table and choose `Show Shapesheet`
3. In the `Shape Transform` section, replace the formulas for `Width` and `Height` with some arbitrary values like `1 in`.
4. Close the ShapeSheet window.
5. Select on the table in question
6. Go to the Developer tab, choose `Protection`, Choose `None`.

Now you can resize the table. Unfortunately, this does not work with multiple tables selected. When multiple tables are selected, only the first table's height and width formulas are replaced which means the other tables selected are still not resizable.

Comment: Any idea how i can resize the bottom part of the table?

Comment: Changing the top and bottom margins on the Text Block tab (Right click on the table shape, choose Format -> Text from the menu) did the trick.